Is every non-orientable manifold exactly half of an orientable manifold?
The question is very clear and very detailed.
I apologize in advance for imprecise title, suggestions are welcome. The question concerns only with smooth manifolds. You can assume they are compact too, for simplicity.
In both senses where manifold $M$ is half of manifold of $N$, we assume that an automorphism $\phi$ of $N$ (a diffeomorphism $\phi:N\rightarrow N$) with $\phi^2=\text{id}$ is given. We also assume the induced relation $\sim$ on $N$ with
$$x\sim y\Leftrightarrow x=\phi(y)$$
Sense 1:
We define $M$ is half of $N$ iff there exists an embedding $\varphi:M\rightarrow N$ such that $\varphi(M)$ and $\phi(\varphi(M))$ cover $N$ and intersect only at their boundaries.
Sense 2:
This is simply $M\cong N/\sim$, i.e. we define $M$ is half of $N$ iff there exists a 2-sheeted smooth covering $\varphi:N\rightarrow M$ such that $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)\Leftrightarrow x\sim y$.
If a manifold is half of another manifold in any sense, they have the same dimension.
Phenomenon 1:
Every manifold with boundary $M$ is half of some manifold without boundary $N$, in sense 1: glue two copies of $M$ at their boundaries.
Phenomenon 2:
Every manifold $M$ is half of some oriented manifold $N$, in sense 2; this is a known fact.
The question:
Can phenomenon 2 be seen through the first sense?
Is it true that for any pair of manifolds $M$ and $N$ such that $M$ is half of $N$ in sense 2, there exists a third manifold $K$ which is half of $M$ in sense 1 so that the assumed automorphisms on $M$ coincide?
Example 1:
Surface $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is one half (in the second sense) of $\mathbb{S}^2$ with relation $x\sim-x$ so any semi-sphere satisfies the condition.
Example 2:
Mobious strip is one half (in the second sense) of the cylinder $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2=1,|z|\leq1\}$ with relation $x\sim-x$ so the cylinder $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2=1,0\leq z\leq1\}$ satisfies the condition.
Some idea:
I thought if I took a random smooth function $f:N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and then antisymmetrized it by redefining $f(x)$ to be $f(x)-f(y)$ (where $x\sim y$) then this new $f$ will have the property that $f=0$ is a smooth submanifold of $N$. Now $K:=\{f\geq0\}$ is the solution. Randomness of $f$ is supposed to guarantee that $f=0$ is a smooth manifold but I don't know how to use it properly.

If a manifold with boundary is non-orientable, so is any manifold of the same dimension it is contained in. Once you have a closed loop which reverses orientation it will still exist in the larger manifold. So sense 1 is impossible.

@CheerfulParsnip But how do my 2 examples still work then?

How is $\Bbb RP^2$ a manifold with boundary? And $\Bbb RP^2$ is in no way a subspace of $S^2$.

Your two examples were in the second sense. If $X$ is a cover of $Y$, $Y$ is not a subset of $X$.

I am sorry, I will rewrite my question to be more clear in an hour. For now, please read again the "question" and take care that $M$ is one half of $N$ in 2nd sense and I am only really asking if there exists $K$ which is half of $N$ in 1st sense so that the relations coincede. Think about what $K$ induces on $M$.

Your question is unclear. Are you asking "Is it true..." (then the answer is negative) or "Does there exist..." (then the answer is positive). But your "idea" makes no sense at all.

@MoisheKohan I edited the body now.

It got even worse, please, proofread what you wrote. And what do "assumed automorphisms" mean? Could you just write a question without all this "half" notions.

@MoisheKohan No.$;;;;;;;$

Haters be hatin'
